# How to save/update Map field in Firestore from SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update my Firestore that has a map as one of the fields from my SwiftUI app. The map will have an integer as a key and a string as a value. My current code stands as:

```
func save(id: String, order: [Int : String]) { //order example: [1 : "Mary", 2: "Susie"...]
        let database = Firestore.firestore()
        database.collection("MyCollection").document(id).setData(
            ["id": id,
             "order": order
            ]) { error in
            if error == nil {
                self.parent.getData()
            }
            else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to save, it throws an error and crashes. I know it is the map saving that is causing the error as if I delete the order field from the update, everything runs fine. I have read the Firebase documentation and it seems like this should be a valid way to save a map, but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: "*it throws an error and crashes*" - In order to make the problem easier for us to understand, you should [study the error message](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/understand-error-messages) and copy its text into the question so that we can see what happened. Without that, we have to guess what went wrong.

Comment: The error message is "An unknown error occurred". If it was a helpful message I would have been able to debug myself or would have included it in the post

Comment: That sounds like what you see in the UI of the simulator, which is not helpful here. You should show what you see in the app logs in xcode, where all the other log messages appear that diagnose what's happening in the app.

Comment: The entire console, minus the normal Firebase analytics, is "An unknown error occurred. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'"

Comment: What's being written to `order` looks like an array. If that is intentional then it would be `["Mary", "Suzie"]` and the indexes would be generated for each element, starting at index 0. Otherwise, keys are always strings in Firestore, not numbers (this is not applicable to an array) if you force Int's, it's interpreted )(coerced) as an array so you could do this ["1": "Mary", "2": "Sally"]. Another option is to prefix the key with a string ["index_1": "Mary", "index_2": Sally].

Comment: @Jay Thank you, that was my problem. In Firestore it seemed like my keys were Ints, but I did not realize they were always saved as strings. I reworked the code to make order a [String : String] map and it all works now. If you want to copy your comment as an answer, I will happily mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's being written to order looks like an array.

If that is intentional then it would be ["Mary", "Suzie"] and the indexes would be generated for each element, starting at index 0.

Otherwise:

> Keys are always strings in Firestore, not numbers

(this is not applicable to an array as it's indexes are auto-generated ints)

If you force Int's, it's interpreted (coerced) as an array so you could do this to avoid Firestore seeing it as an array

```
["1": "Mary", "2": "Sally"]
```

Another option is to prefix the key with a string

```
["index_1": "Mary", "index_2": Sally]
```

The one downside is: if you use Strings and need ordering, you'll end up with string ordering intead of numeric; e.g. "1", "2", "3", "10", "11" would sort at "1", "10", "11", "2", "3" so padding the numbers will fix that "01", "02", "03", "10", "11" will sort correctly.